# Clamav-base no archive found

Tags: clamav

Clamav-base must become reinstalled in 16.04. Cannot start synaptic package for this reason. anybody a solution?? Commands " sudo apt-get install clamav." does not work. The system returns with "clamav-base must be reinstalled, cannot find archive.

```
peter@peter-HP-Pavilion-Desktop-PC-570-p0XX:~$ sudo apt-get install --reinstall clamav-base clamav
[sudo] wachtwoord voor peter: 
Pakketlijsten worden ingelezen... Klaar
Boom van vereisten wordt opgebouwd       
De statusinformatie wordt gelezen... Klaar
E: Pakket clamav-base moet opnieuw geïnstalleerd worden, maar er kan geen archief voor gevonden worden.
peter@peter-HP-Pavilion-Desktop-PC-570-p0XX:~$ 

Starten van synaptic via terminal geeft de volgende foutmelding
E: Pakket clamav-base moet opnieuw geïnstalleerd worden, maar er kan geen archief voor gevonden worden.
E: Interne fout bij openen van buffer (1). Gaarne melden.
```

Comment: `sudo apt-get install --reinstall clamav-base clamav`. The clamav issue is not why synaptic won't start. Give me exact error messages if you start synaptic in `terminal`.

Comment: The exact error messages have been added to the question. Thanks so far

Comment: `sudo apt-get purge clamav-base clamav` then `sudo apt-get install clamav-base clamav`. Report back.

Comment: Have just (a couple of minutes ago) reinstalled the sources.list according to page "https://sites.google.com/site/computertip/bronnen" het werkt nu weer althans het synaptic pakket beheer. Bedankt voor de informatie en het werk. als claav base weer verschijnt dan zal ik jouw oplossing proberen.

Comment: You shouldn't have followed the instructions at that web site. You removed .list files that you shouldn't have.